# Instance roles for Azure vms

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine, rbac, azure-role-environment

Basically I'm trying to implement with Azure the following AWS pattern:

- Assign an IAM role to an Vm (Aws instance equivalent)
- Allow this role to access a certain container (AWS bucket equivalent) as read only and download from there

How it this possible with Azure?

Comment: I need to add Active Directory Domain Services role to a domain controller (VM). I can't find the role in IAM.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Preview with "Managed Service Identity" (MSI)

Linux doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/msi-tutorial-linux-vm-access-storage

Windows doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/msi-tutorial-windows-vm-access-storage

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to IAM in AWS to Azure is [Role-Based Access Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is) .

You can use [Role-Based Access Control to manage access to your Azure subscription resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure).

Also if you wish you can create custom roles you can refer this, [Creating custom roles for Azure Role-Based Access Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles).

You can refer this for custom user roles, [Assign custom roles for internal and external users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-create-custom-roles-for-internal-external-users)

Comment: Thanks but but those resources don't seem to support Assigning a role to a vm, Which is the actual question. Any clues about that?

Answer (score 0):

> Allow this role to access a certain container (AWS bucket equivalent)
>   as read only and download from there.

For now, Azure does not support AD-based authentication or ACLs.

As a workaround, we can use shared access signatures (SAS).

> A shared access signature (SAS) provides you with a way to grant
>   limited access to objects in your storage account to other clients,
>   without exposing your account key.

More information about Azure SAS, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1).